# Someone please tell me what is wrong with my $.parseJSON [javascript / jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is my tested result. I run my app, I get the `"Hello"` alert. But I don't get `"After parse JSON"` alert.

When I comment out the `var rstList = $.parseJSON(data);` line, "After parse JSON" alert prompted correctly.

I have check many document and reference but couldn't find out what is wrong with my `$.parseJSON()`. Please advice, thank you.

```
//Show restaurant listing
$('#restaurantList').on("pagebeforecreate", function() {
    $.getJSON("http://mydomain/api/restaurant", function( data ) {
    alert('Hello');
    var rstList = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert('After parse JSON');

    });
});
```

Comment: Did you check the error console? It's there for a reason!

Comment: after alert('hello'); write console.log(data). now execute code check console and paste console result here

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, if you don't intend to help, please save your time and strength to not even typing out "Did you check the error console? It's there for a reason!". You're telling me My-Sister-Is-A-Girl. Your comment doesn't help at all and it shows your attitude...

Comment: Actually, if you'd actually checked the error console, you would have seen an error message - I know this for a fact because otherwise `alert` would be running! So the fact that you are complaining shows that you *still* haven't bothered to look.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, if there is any error log, my eye will send signal to my brain telling me there is an error and maybe a hint. But too bad... There isn't. I wonder how you can be so sure I "still haven't bothered to look."? This is my last reply for you. My time are valuable too.

Comment: If the `alert` before `parseJSON` is being called, but the one after is not, then the code is dying in that `parseJSON` call. The only reason that would happen is *because of an error*. So... yeah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to what the name implies, `$.getJSON` doesn't give you some JSON but the result of the parsing.

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) :

> The success callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a
>   JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed
>   using the $.parseJSON() method.

You `data` is already parsed, don't parse it.

BTW, as Niet commented, you should have looked at the console to have a little more information on the error halting your script's execution. See [Using the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console).

Comment: Hi, how should I access the data then? I tried: **alert(data.name[0]);** but not working.

Comment: @user3053891 Log your data in the console : `console.log(data)` to know more.

Comment: @Andy, thank you so much. I'll learn more on how to handle data access.  Still new to JS/jQuery. Thanks again.

Comment: `data[0].name` means that `data` is an array and you're getting the value of the `name` property of the first object in that array.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to parse a json object again. Which causes the error. $.getJSON
will return the json object. You dont need to parse it again

Comment: I tried to access the data with: **alert(data.name[0]);** but failed. I may have calling it the wrong way. Please correct me, thank you.